# What are square braces surrounding attribute values?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, tfs, build-process

In the TFS DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml build process template, there are many attributes whose entire values are surrounded by square braces `[]`, so a tag has the form

`<tagName attributeName="[attributeValue]">`

where `tagName`, `attributeName`, and `attributeValue` are text strings.

I cannot find any documentation for this value syntax. From the template, it appears to cause the XAML processor to evaluate the text as an expression. Is this explained somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that square braces in XAML do indeed denote a value expression. I am still uncertain exactly how this denotation is supported or enforced. Possibilities include:

-XAML syntax; I think this is the most likely answer.

-A [Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) implementation somewhere which detects during parsing when a value begins and ends with square braces, and evaluates the content within during processing; I think this is the second-most likely answer.

-It's possible that the square braces are actually not special characters and are valid as part of an identifier, the evaluation of the value is performed via some other as yet unknown mechanism, and the square braces are present by convention only, perhaps to indicate that the value is not a literal but an expression to be evaluated. I think this is an unlikely answer.

Supporting research:

> ["Expressions created in the WF designer are serialized using square brackets, which is shorthand for VisualBasicValue or VisualBasicReference"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cathyk/archive/2010/01/26/expression-serialization-and-literal-support.aspx)
>
> ["Hand edit the workflow XAML file to change value of the Number property to [1+2] (the square brackets denote an expression)"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cathyk/archive/2009/12/15/expressiontextbox-for-arguments-only.aspx)
>
> ["Expressions are literal values or Visual Basic code bound to arguments or properties. They contain value elements (e.g. variables, constants, literals, properties) that are combined with operations to yield a new value. Expressions are written using VB.NET syntax even if the application is in a program using C#."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd797416.aspx)
>
> ["Workflows produced by designer are saved in XAML, where expressions appear enclosed in square brackets."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489455.aspx)

The last quote above is the only official documentation I have found that in any way mentions the square brace surrounding expressions as XAML attribute values, and this still does not clarify whether the designer does this merely arbitrarily and without invoking any special syntax, or if expressions must appear enclosed in square brackets according to the official XAML specification and as such the designer must do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is a property that is set before in your XAML like this for example: `<x:Property Name="BuildNumberFormat" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />` If you open the build process templates in VS 2012 you are able to change/customize them using `Workflow`.

Comment: I think that is not correct unless you can provide links to documentation. [This page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cathyk/archive/2010/01/26/expression-serialization-and-literal-support.aspx) says "Expressions created in the WF designer are serialized using square brackets, which is shorthand for VisualBasicValue<T> or VisualBasicReference<T>" and [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cathyk/archive/2009/12/15/expressiontextbox-for-arguments-only.aspx) says " Hand edit the workflow XAML file to change value of the Number property to [1+2] (the square brackets denote an expression)".

Comment: Other guesses: a square-braced expression is an "immediate reference" to a "key" or "index". Also: "A small number of XAML elements can directly process text as their content."[^](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx). Also: "BAML form is an optimized form of XAML used by the WPF XAML implementation. It is optimized in the sense that it uses internal lookups and tokens for commonly used types or members."[^](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.baml2006.baml2006reader.aspx) Is the square brace such an "internal token"?

Comment: To be complete the Property that I showed above is an Argument in the Process template. So when you open the BP Template you see at the bottom a tab `Arguments` and there you'll find all the properties that are used further in the XAML file.

Comment: I'm asking about the syntax of the value expression in XAML, not about the specific `Argument`s used in this process template. The `Default value` field in the `Arguments` tab displays the hint "Enter a VB expression", so I am fairly certain at this point that square-bracketed attribute values denote VB expressions that are evaluated during XAML parsing/processing, but I can't actually find any official documentation that explains this. Perhaps `[` and `]` are not treated as special characters and are in fact a valid part of an identifier string, only conventionally denoted expressions?

Comment: Also: "Single Indexer on the Immediate Object as Data Context <Binding Path="[key]" .../>"[^](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx) "Inside indexers....For example, you can have Path="[(sys:Int32)42,(sys:Int32)24]"[^](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) The second quote here is an example of the type of syntax to which I refer.

Comment: ["Expressions are literal values or Visual Basic code bound to arguments or properties. They contain value elements (e.g. variables, constants, literals, properties) that are combined with operations to yield a new value. Expressions are written using VB.NET syntax even if the application is in a program using C#."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd797416.aspx) Still doesnt say expressions use `[...]` in XAML. From DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml: `<If Condition="[Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DropLocation)]" DisplayName="If DropLocation is Set" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">`